# XSL to produce all element and attribute names

Tags: xml, xslt

I need two XSL style sheets that evaluate any XML document and returns:

1) all element names within their hierarchy;

2) all attribute names associated with each element; and

3) one style sheet that output the result to XML; one style sheet that outputs the result to text.

I will transform this in SSIS, which I have done quite a few times including with basic XSL style sheets that I've created.  I will be loading this into a table within a database.

Please note that I possess minimal knowledge of XSL/XML.  I may use incorrect terms.  Also I may overlook something obvious in my request.  Therefore I would rely on you to apply your insights.

Example XML:

```
<BOOK id="1" chapters="9">
    <AUTHOR gender="Male" age="43">
        <NAME>John Smith</NAME>
    </AUTHOR>
    <TITLE>Just a book</TITLE>
</BOOK>
```

Desired text output (two columns delimited by tab or some character):

```
element    attribute
/BOOK    id
/BOOK    chapters
/BOOK/AUTHOR    gender
/BOOK/AUTHOR    age
/BOOK/AUTHOR/NAME 
/BOOK/TITLE
```

Desired XML output (more or less? not sure; open to suggestions):

```
<ROOT>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK</ELEMENT><ATTRIBUTE>id</ATTRIBUTE>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK</ELEMENT><ATTRIBUTE>chapters</ATTRIBUTE>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/AUTHOR</ELEMENT>gender<ATTRIBUTE></ATTRIBUTE>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/AUTHOR</ELEMENT>age<ATTRIBUTE></ATTRIBUTE>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/AUTHOR/NAME</ELEMENT>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/TITLE</ELEMENT>
</ROOT>
```

I don't want to be a mooch and this is more than a little question so I would be willing to pay for the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't stated it in the requirement, but my guess is that you only want *distinct* element/attribute name pairs. @MadsHansen interpreted your requirements differently, which just goes to show how careful you need to be with requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the desired XML with the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ROOT>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[not(@*)]|//@*" />
        </ROOT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <ELEMENT><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="path"/></ELEMENT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".." />
        <ATTRIBUTE><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></ATTRIBUTE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*/name(.)" separator="/"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then enhance it to be able to generate either the desired XML or text output by setting the value of the *format* parameter to "text". Setting the *format* parameter value to anything else will generate the XML output. You can adjust the delimiter value by setting a different value for the *delim* parameter.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="format" select="'text'"/>

    <xsl:param name="delim" select="'   '"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <!--generate XML report and assign to a variable-->
      <xsl:variable name="report">
        <ROOT>
          <!--Push elements that don't have attributes, and all attributes.
              Elements that have attributes will be transformed when
              transforming the attributes -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[not(@*)] | //@*" />
        </ROOT>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!--depending upon the value of the format parameter, 
          either transform that XML into the text report,
          or return the generated XML -->  
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$format='text'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$report/ROOT"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:sequence select="$report"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <ELEMENT><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="path"/></ELEMENT>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--for each attribute, generate an ELEMENT with the path and an ATTRIBUTE element-->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".." />
        <ATTRIBUTE><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></ATTRIBUTE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*/name(.)" separator="/"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--templates to transform the generated XML into the text output -->
    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <xsl:sequence select="string-join(('element', 'attribute'), $delim)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ELEMENT"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ELEMENT">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join((., following-sibling::*[1][self::ATTRIBUTE]), $delim)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am grateful for your response.  This returned the following error: "Expected end of the expression, found '('.".

Comment: This is an XSLT 2.0 solution. It sounds as if you may be using a 1.0 engine. It would be helpful to state in the question if you are limited to XSLT 1.0. Tag it with `xslt-1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, requirements:

(a) your example doesn't have any instances where there is more than one element or attribute with the same path, so it's not clear whether or not you want to eliminate duplicates.

(b) your output XML is quite tricky to process, because the element paths and attribute names aren't connected except by relative position. It would be better to add a wrapper element, say `<PATH>`.

(c) in your output, the number of times an element path appears is N where N is the number of attributes found, except that it is 1 when there are no attributes. This seems a little inconsistent to me. I would suggest output of the form

```
<ROOT>
  <PATH>    
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK</ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTE>id</ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE>chapters</ATTRIBUTE>
  </PATH>
  <PATH>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/AUTHOR</ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTE>gender<ATTRIBUTE>
    <ATTRIBUTE>age</ATTRIBUTE>
  <PATH>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/AUTHOR/NAME</ELEMENT>
  </PATH>
  <PATH>
    <ELEMENT>/BOOK/AUTHOR/TITLE</ELEMENT>
  </PATH>
</ROOT>
```

If I'm right in thinking that you want to eliminate duplicates, then this is a grouping problem and therefore much easier in XSLT 2.0+. You didn't actually state any constraints on XSLT version, but I'm going to assume XSLT 2.0. Note that there are many XSLT processors that only support 1.0, even though 2.0 has been out for over ten years.

First we want a function that gives the path to an element:

```
<xsl:function name="f:path" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="exists($node/..)">
      <xsl:sequence select="concat(f:path($node/..), '/', local-name($node)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>/</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

Now the grouping commences:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//*" group-by="f:path(.)">
  <PATH>
    <ELEMENT><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></ELEMENT>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/@*" group-by="local-name()">
      <ATTRIBUTE><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></ATTRIBUTE>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </PATH>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I am grateful for your response.

This only produced: "John SmithJust a book".

Comment: When the result of a transformation is just the text node content of the input, that usually suggests that none of the code in the stylesheet is being executed. I didn't give you a complete stylesheet, just the critical parts; I suspect there's something wrong in the code that you added.